# How to prevent XSS attacks in Django REST API CharFields?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working on an app using Django 2.2 with djangorestframework 3.9.2. I am aware that Django itself provides protection against SQL Injection or in in the context of displaying content in django templates (XSS), but I've noticed that while I use Django REST API, all the CharFields in my models are not sanitized automatically.

**Note: this question does not apply to django templates.**

E.g. having a direct messages model (`message/models.py`):

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(...)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(...)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(...)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Actually does not prevent anyone from sending a message with content `<script>alert("Hello there");</script>`. It will be saved in database and returned by the REST API as is, allowing to remotely run any JS script (basically a Cross Site Scripting).

Is this an expected behavior? **How can this be prevented?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`escape()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.escape) method inside serializer's validation:

```
from django.utils.html import escape

class MySerializer:
    def validate_myfield(self, value):
        return escape(value)
```

Comment: this seems like a most relevant answer as of today

Answer (score 9):

Django (or DRF) doesn't escape any html/text content going into the database. Text is only escaped when displaying it using the template system (unless it's marked as safe at some point).

The reason for this is that Django doesn't really know what you will be using this text for. For some use cases it might be perfectly fine to store HTML, including script tags.

If you are looking for a way to sanitize input before it goes into the database I can recommend Mozilla's `bleach` library: https://github.com/mozilla/bleach

I haven't used `django-bleach` (https://django-bleach.readthedocs.io/) but it seems like a convenient way to integrate `bleach` into `Django`.

Comment: I've found out about django-bleach earlier, but it does not seem relevant nowadays, and although it works fine, the tests all fail without any clear reason (the console says `TypeError: argument cannot be of 'NoneType' type, must be of text type` even for fields, that are not handled by bleach). Still, your reply does answer my question, thank you.